# Stylesheet for smart devices only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I have two stylesheets, one is core.css and the other one is tablet-and-mobile.css as you can see below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/core.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="assets/css/tablet-and-mobile.css" />
```

Go to [www.loaistudio.com](http://www.loaistudio.com) and start re-sizing the width from above 1024px to below so it applies the tablet and phone stylesheet.

Can you notice that the elements are jumping? that is because some of them has:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
```

HOW to fix this problem! I need the transitions to be on them, but is there anyway to prevent the jumping from happening?

Comment: Tablets and mobile devices don't have resizable browser windows. Therefore, this is a non-issue. Anyway, resizing of browser windows isn't a common action and really isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: You are completely right I agree! It is just this will be the template that my clients will use to see an example of a responsive website, this is a template they will keep re-sizing and play with. Please is there any way I can fix it? :/

Comment: @Blazemonger is right on the money: smart devices don't have resizable viewports, and real desktop users don't spend time continuously re-sizing their viewport to see what happens.

Comment: You (and probably all other developers) need to explain to your client that resizing the browser is not a real use case and is also _not the point_ of responsive design. Serving optimized content to the user on every device; that's the point of responsive design.

Comment: @Mathletics your statement is misguided. Real users CAN and WILL resize their browsers. That's responsive design. Adaptive design is serving optimized content for device. It's quite realistic for someone to expect content to move fluidly when a user resizes their browser.

Comment: AGREE with @disinfor can you guys please help me find a solution rather argue on this. Please

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is your application of transitions to `all` properties. Supplement these rules with an additional `transition-property`, and include a comma-separated list of only the properties you want to transition. For example:

```
transition-property: opacity, max-height;
```

This will incidentally save a lot of computing time!

Comment: Can I do something like this? transition-property: width 0.2s ease-out;

Comment: @Leo absolutely! If you have multiple properties you want to transition but want them all to share the same transition properties (speed, easing), the method above would help.

Comment: [Older browsers don't support transitions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), but using prefixes as you did in your sample code will mitigate that to some degree.

Comment: So I basically add -webkit-,-moz- etc. before yea?

Comment: So It will be somthing like-webkit-transition-property: width 0.2s ease-out;

Comment: No: if you just want to animate one property (`width`), you can write `transition: width 0.2 ease-out;` — you would only need to specify `transition-property` (as well as your original `transition` property if you wanted to specify multiple properties to transition.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a question about this, only the opposite. You need to apply a **-device-** call to the query to have it just affect phones and tablets.

`media="screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)"`

If you had this call in the CSS file itself it would be:
`@media only screen and (max-device-width:1024px)` or whatever `device-width` you want to target.

Here's a good website for device queries: www.stephentgilbert.com/mediaqueries/

Comment: I should have put, you don't need the @media for your example. Did you just try `media="screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)"`

Comment: Here's another site to check out: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/ about serving CSS based on device as opposed to just browser width